# Magento 1 show pop when product added to cart

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart, messages

Is there an easy way to show a popup that a product is added to the cart in Magento 1.9? The popup message itself will be no problem to create, but I need the code-part that checks and shows the message when a product is added.

We disabled the default method to redirect directly to the cart when the product is added. Magento does show the message in the message block, can we use some code from that?

I am not looking for a AJAX solution, it will be fine that the page reloads and the message is then displayed.

Some any ideas?

Comment: does you website having `Bootstrap ` or `fancy box` ?

Comment: @Pawan Yes we have bootstrap. But like I said, the popup itself (html, css,js) is no problem. I just need to code to display this once a product is added to the cart successfully.